# Javascript Detail Page Toggle Button

Tags: javascript, custom-button

I am trying to create a custom button on the detail page of the Account object.  The button will simply toggle a checkbox field from true to false and vice versa.  The code below works for the "IF" condition, but it does nothing for the "ELSE" condition.  If I switch the 2, it also works.  Does anyone know why my ELSE statement is being ignored when the button is clicked?

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/22.0/connection.js")} 
var updateRecords = []; 
var a = new sforce.SObject("Account"); 
a.id ="{!Account.Id}";

if(a.No_Parent_Account__c = "true"){
a.No_Parent_Account__c = "false";
}else{
a.No_Parent_Account__c = "true";
}
newRecords.push(a); 
result = sforce.connection.update(updateRecords); 
window.location.reload();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to specify that field, or it won't be available to you in your code. Do this instead:

```
{!RequireScript("/soap/ajax/35.0/connection.js")}
var a = new sforce.SObject("Account");
a.id = "{!Account.Id}";
a.No_Parent_Account__c = !{!Account.No_parent_Account__c};
sforce.connection.update([a]);
window.location.reload();
```

Since No_Parent_Account__c is a Boolean value, you don't need to surround it in quotes; this also makes it easier to read the code. Also note the use of the ! negation operator to remove that unnecessary if statement.

Comment: Thanks so much, that did the trick!!  Much simpler code!

Comment: Sorry for hijacking this, but what would be a valid 1 click lightning experience alternative? http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/159497/looking-for-lightning-alternative-for-javascript-detail-page-toggle-button

Comment: @ChristianSzandorKnapp It's okay, I don't mind. You've got a few different solutions to your question. See if any of those help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Change your if statement to:

```
if(a.No_Parent_Account__c == "true"){
```

And don't forget to retrieve the record first

```
var accts = sforce.connection.query("SELECT No_Parent_Account__c FROM Account WHERE Id = '{!Account.Id}'");

records = accts.getArray("records");

var a = records[0];
```

So, your complete sample would be

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/22.0/connection.js")} 
var updateRecords = []; 
var a = new sforce.SObject("Account"); 

var accts = sforce.connection.query("SELECT No_Parent_Account__c FROM Account WHERE Id = '{!Account.Id}'");

records = accts.getArray("records");

var a = records[0];

if(a.No_Parent_Account__c == "true"){
a.No_Parent_Account__c = "false";
}else{
a.No_Parent_Account__c = "true";
}
newRecords.push(a); 
result = sforce.connection.update(updateRecords); 
window.location.reload();
```

Comment: Thanks.  I made that change, but the behavior is the same, it's still ignoring the "else" portion.

Comment: Strange, hard to tell without looking at your data. Try doing a "console.log(a.No_Parent_Account__c)" or an "alert(a.No_Parent_Account__c)" before the if statement so you can verify that your comparing against the right value

Comment: I tried both.  The "alert" returns an error box that just says Undefined.  The console.log just mimics the same behavior of ignoring the else.

Comment: that explains. you're not retrieving the value from the DB before evaluating. Not sure really how to do that. Will research and updte my post. UPDATE: Done, with new code

Comment: @SebastianKessel There's really no need to do *all that work* in a custom button.

Comment: Yeah, just saw your code, much simpler. Upvoted yours. Left mine b/c it could help other people in similar (but not quite identical) situations... as in when they have to update other objects.

Comment: @SebastianKessel Indeed. Sometimes you do need to query, like children records, parent records (sometimes), etc. Your code is still definitely useful.